# Net Core API not returning all children DB First

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Below is my code. I'm wondering if I might be better off using something else. I feel like this should be a fairly simple return.

Repository:

```
public Task<OrderHistory> GetInvoicedMacolaOrder(string orderNumber)
            {
                orderNumber = " " + orderNumber;
                DataContext.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    
                    var order = DataContext.OrderHistory
                                    .Include(order => order.OrderLines)
                                    .ThenInclude(line =>  line.vw_uniqueCartonIds)
                                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(o => o.ord_no == orderNumber);
                    
                return order;
            }
```

OrderHistoryController:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "CreateReplacementOrder")]
        [HttpGet("invoicedorder/{orderNumber}/get")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> OrderLookUp(string orderNumber)
        {
            if (PoExists(orderNumber))
            {
                
                var order = await _mrepo.GetInvoicedOrder(orderNumber);
               
                var orderToReturn = _mapper.Map<OrderHistoryDtoDetail>(order);

                return Ok(orderToReturn);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Could not find order number.");
            }
        }
```

This is what returns:

```
 {
        "ord_no": "51464326",
        "status": "P",
        "ord_dt": "2020-03-29T00:00:00",
        "apply_to_no": null,
        "oe_po_no": "3804339            ",
        "cus_no": "65564654018",
        "ship_to_name": "Omar Brown"
        "OrderLines": [
            {
                "ord_type": "O",
                "ord_no": "51464326",
                "line_seq_no": 1,
                "item_no": "jkhhuk",
                "line_no": 1,
                "vw_uniqueCartonIds": [
                    {
                        "box_id": 20,
                        "prod_cat": "044",
                        "box_number": 1,
                        "uniqueBoxID": "100001"
                    },
                    {
                        "box_id": 20,
                        "prod_cat": "044",
                        "box_number": 2,
                        "uniqueBoxID": "100002"
                    },
                   {
                        "box_id": 20,
                        "prod_cat": "044",
                        "box_number": 3,
                        "uniqueBoxID": "100003"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

What I'm expecting:

```
{
            "ord_no": "51464326",
            "status": "P",
            "ord_dt": "2020-03-29T00:00:00",
            "apply_to_no": null,
            "oe_po_no": "3804339            ",
            "cus_no": "65564654018",
            "ship_to_name": "Omar Brown"
            "OrderLines": [
                {
                    "ord_type": "O",
                    "ord_no": "51464326",
                    "line_seq_no": 1,
                    "item_no": "jkhhuk",
                    "line_no": 1,
                    "vw_uniqueCartonIds": [
                        {
                            "box_id": 20,
                            "prod_cat": "044",
                            "box_number": 1,
                            "uniqueBoxID": "100001"
                        },
                        {
                            "box_id": 21,
                            "prod_cat": "044",
                            "box_number": 2,
                            "uniqueBoxID": "100002"
                        },
                       {
                            "box_id": 22,
                            "prod_cat": "044",
                            "box_number": 3,
                            "uniqueBoxID": "100003"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "ord_type": "O",
                    "ord_no": "51464326",
                    "line_seq_no": 2,
                    "item_no": "58hhuk",
                    "line_no": 2,
                    "vw_uniqueCartonIds": [
                        {
                            "box_id": 25,
                            "prod_cat": "054",
                            "box_number": 1,
                            "uniqueBoxID": "200001"
                        },
                        {
                            "box_id": 26,
                            "prod_cat": "054",
                            "box_number": 2,
                            "uniqueBoxID": "200002"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

Also I have seen the posts about ReferenceLoopHandling and added that to my startup.cs file,but to no avail.

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
                {
                    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                        .Build();

                    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));

                })
               .AddNewtonsoftJson(opt =>
                {
                    opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                });
```

What causes the problem?

Comment: It might help if you debug it to narrow down the problem since it seems like it could be an issue in the repository, in `_mapper.Map`, or in serialization

Comment: Also, it may be a typo but you are calling `GetInvoicedOrder` from your controller but have shown the implementation of `GetInvoicedMacolaOrder`

Comment: If you want ALL then why are you using .FirstOrDefaultAsync(o => o.ord_no == orderNumber);

Comment: @jdweng I'm new to .net in general what else can I use?

Comment: Try ForEachAsync instead of FirstOrDefaultAsync

Comment: Do you have "line_no": 2 in your DB ?

Comment: Can you paste your map code

Comment: You need to check value of `var order` to see if you are getting expected the data from database. If you are getting correct data from database then you have a problem in mapping logic. Also check if you are getting correct data in `var orderToReturn`

Comment: So I ran a different order that had two line items and it worked fine. I think it must be a data issue. I looked at the first order I was trying and the column from OrderLines that joins to vw_uniqueCartonIds was the same on both line items. Was it simply trying to avoid duplicates?